# Using selection in reduce block

Tags: ruby, reduce

What is the effective way to separate the logic by 2 selections in reduce block ?

i mean, sum if choice equal 1, product if choice equal 2

this is my code but it does not look for if choice equal 2. it works for only choice 1 and the others.

```
(1..10).reduce(choice == 1 ? :+ : :*)
```

How can i handle choice 1 and choice 2 in the same reduce block ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code--it works fine.  Wait a minute, I'm wondering why @DigitalRoss would suggest a solution that is identical to what you have.  Aha! You edited away your original question.  Now why would you do that, just to confuse us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *almost* worked. You need:

```
(1..10).reduce(choice == 1 ? :+ : :*)
```

*Update:* it turns out the real issue was the need for an expression template that would not simply default to the scalar product. Apparently throwing an exception (when *choice* is out of range) is either OK or at least a useful template place-holder. A couple of expressions then come to mind:

```
(1..10).reduce({1 => :+, 2 => :*}[choice])
(1..10).reduce([nil, :+, :*][choice])
```

Comment: yes but i dont want to product if choice equal 3.. it must work only if choice equal 2

Comment: What do you want to happen in the *not-1-and-not-2* case?  If throwing an exception is OK, I would do this: `(1..10).reduce({1 => :+, 2 => :*}[choice])` or perhaps this: `(1..10).reduce([nil, :+, :*][choice])`

Comment: yes throwing an exception..i tried the code but returns nothing ?

Comment: oh sorry..this was my irb mistake. i works now. its fine thaks.